# Can SQL Server 2008 Express be used for offering commercial web hosting services?

Tags: sql-server

I read that SQL Server 2008 Express R2 database size limit has increased to 10G. That's good news.

Can I use the Express edition of SQL Server to offer web hosting services to the public? Microsoft should be best in answering this but I can't find a clear answer on their site.

I am also seeing several Windows web hosting plans include SQL Server as a total package for less than $5/month. I am wondering how they can afford to offer this.

Comment: I upvoted the selected answer, it at least deserves a +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do providers offer SQL Server at $5/mo? You need to become a service provider and buy volume licensing. See [Licensing Options For Services Providers](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/spla-program.aspx). Contact Microsoft for details and pricing.

As for Express and hosting, see this guidelines from the [Express weblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-server-express-and-hosting.aspx):

> Several questions have come up lately
>   regarding whether SQL Server Express
>   is an appropriate product to be used
>   in a hosting environment.  Here are
>   the answers:
>   - **User Instances** (also known
>   as RANU) available with SQL Server
>   Express Edition, are NOT RECOMMENDED
>   for hosting environments.
>    - **Shared hosting**: SQL Server
>   Express Edition is NOT RECOMMENDED for
>   shared (multi-tenant) hosting as the
>   scale limits and memory handling do
>   not allow it to meet the requirements
>   of such an environment.  SQL Server
>   Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition
>   are the best choice for shared
>   hosting.
>   -  **Dedicated hosting**: All
>   versions of SQL Server including
>   Express Edition are RECOMMENDED for
>   dedicated (single-tenant) hosting
>   environments.  SQL Server Express
>   Edition is a great way to provide a
>   free copy of SQL Server with low cost
>   Windows Server offerings.  Where
>   customers require more advanced
>   features or higher scale, Workgroup
>   Edition, Standard Edition, and
>   Enterprise Edition are all options.

And there is also this whitepaper [SQL Server 2005 Deployment Guidance for Web Hosting Environments](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966485.aspx).

Most of this guidance is for SQL Server 2005, but it largely applies to 2008 and 2008 R2, from a technical point of view. As for licensing questions, as always, contact an Microsoft representative.

Comment: That looks like an interesting offering, but is it _necessary_ in order to use SQL Server Express in a hosting scenario?

Comment: @John: I have detailed my answer

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of anything in the licences that would prevent this.  MS actually has some very nice EULA's.  As for the total package they are probably accessing a single server using different table spaces in order to split the cost.  The various tablespaces (or whatever the MS equivalent is) can be located on different FSs to prevent contamination.

Comment: This is exactly what they are doing.  They set up space for numerous clients per server.  One provider I was on for a little while had misconfigured their database server and I was able to see the complete list of database names on that server (though I could not access them).  The list numbered several hundred long.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can use express edition for use in hosting server.